# How do I stop the remote client showing all folders even unloaded ones?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I am using Clearteam Explorer 8. I recently was browsing a project folder which contained a symbolic link. Explorer said that I would need to enable something in order to follow the link. I said ok.

Now it insists on showing me every possible folder in all of my views including unloaded ones. The folders have no contents, but it makes all views really hard to navigate as there is a lot of chaff in the view's tree.

I cannot find where this option is set/unset because I set it in response to a one-time prompt. Does anyone know how to turn this off and have it only show me loaded folders?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Load Rules tab of the ["Edit Configuration" dialog box](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Fu_edit_config.htm), for Web views only, if you have the option "Show Obsolete Directories and Files" selected.
Un-selecting this option might help.

---

If you can [edit the config spec of your view](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Fu_edit_config.htm), you can add cleaning rules, like:

```
element /avob/* -none
```

If you placed it just before the last one (element * /main/LATEST), that would hep ClearCase to *not* select at all any element which wasn't already selected before by the config spec selection rules.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the ideas. The "Show Obsolete Directories and Files" is not selected on any of my views.
I added the config spec element, but nothing changed. The thing is, none of the other files not mentioned in my config spec are actually loaded. It just shows me reams of empty folder trees in ClearTeam Explorer. The empty folders aren't actually copied to my hard drive either.
For some reason whatever got changed in the CTE settings is something that shows me all unloaded folders in CTE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by:

1. Removing the parameter `ccvtreeviewer.fetchFullTree=true` from file `com.ibm.rational.clearcase.prefs`. On my machine, this file is located in folder: `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\.Rational\CTE8\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\com.ibm.rational.clearcase.prefs`
2. Editing the file `com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.model.prefs` and update theses parameters:

```
appliedTreeRules_0=com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.ShowLoadedVobsAction|Public and Private VOBs|true|true|true|System;

nonappliedTreeRules_0=com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.ShowUnloadedVobsAction|Unloaded VOBs|true|false|false|System;com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.ShowUnloadedElementsAction|Unloaded Elements|true|false|false|System;com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.ShowLoadedPrivateVobsAction|Private VOBs only|true|true|false|System;com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.ShowLoadedPublicVobsAction|Public VOBs only|true|true|false|System;com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.ShowUnmountedVobsAction|Unmounted VOBs|true|false|false|System;
```